# Apache mod_auth_kerb and LDAP user groups

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, kerberos, single-sign-on

I've been considering deploying `mod_auth_kerb` on our internal web servers to enable SSO. The one obvious problem I can see is that it's an all-or-nothing approach, either all your domain users can access a site or not.

Is it possible to combine `mod_auth_kerb` with something like `mod_authnz_ldap` to check for group membership in a particular group in LDAP? I'm guessing the `KrbAuthoritative` option would have something to do with this?

Also, as I understand it, the module sets the username to be `username@REALM` after authentication, but of course in the directory the users are stored as the username only. Furthermore, some internal sites we run such as trac already have a user profile linked to each username. Is there a way to resolve this, perhaps by stripping off the realm bit after authentication somehow?

Comment: Just a question regarding implementation, are you using a Windows ADS for the kerberos realm or some other implementation?

Comment: Apple's OpenDirectory which comes with MIT Kerberos v5

Comment: Okay... Haven't worked with Apple's OpenDirectory before. I was able to get Apache to authenticate using NTLM against Windows ADS using their workstation credentials and then restricting to specific groups.

Comment: Without stripping realm from username, you can use an alternate attribute in LDAP query to search for user entity, for instance the "userPrincipalName" attribute in Ms ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is now possible in mod_auth_kerb 5.4 to strip the realm from REMOTE_USER with the following config directive:

KrbLocalUserMapping On

Comment: Wow, looks like this was released in 2008, but no mention of it (the version or the parameter) on their website.

Answer (score 7):

It's the whole point of the authn/authz separation in 2.2 that you can authenticate with one mechanism, and authorize with another. Authentication provides you with a setting of REMOTE_USER, which you then can use authz_ldap against. In addition, authn_ldap searches then for a user (converting the REMOTE_USER to a DN if found, using search criteria you have to specify - e.g. searching for CN). Then, when a DN has been found, you can specify requirements on the LDAP object. E.g. if all users accessing a resource must be in the same OU, you specify

require ldap-dn ou=Managers, o=The Company

Comment: Is it possible to modify the REMOTE_USER variable before it's passed to the authorization stage? For example, to strip off the REALM portion of the Kerberos username for lookup in an LDAP database?

Comment: Not by means of configuration. However, it is relatively easy to do so in the source code of the Apache module. Look for assignments to request->user and adjust them; then rebuild the module with apxs2 -c. OTOH, it might be easier to put the Kerberos names into LDAP, under a separate attribute, and have the ldap module search the user by that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Debian stable now ships with version 5.4 of [mod_auth_kerb](http://packages.debian.org/fr/squeeze/libapache2-mod-auth-kerb).

If you're stuck with an older version, [this page](http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/15/mod_auth_kerb-ad-and-ldap-authorization/) explains how mod_map_user can be used in combination with mod_auth_kerb and mod_authnz_ldap.